# reload a div again without using load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form through which I want to upload a user's name which works fine but want to display it right after he uploads it by clicking "Save" button(of submit type)  without reloading the page.Right now, the name is getting uploaded but appears only when I reload the page.Any suggestions?Please dont suggest using load() as it has compatibility problem with different browsers.

```
  <div id="nameform">
    //contains code to upload name via form
    </div>

<div id="name">
<?php 
$query1=mysqli_query($dbc,"select * from users where Email='".$_SESSION['Email']."'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
$name=$row['name'];
if ($name!="")
 echo "$name";
else echo "Your name please....";
?>
</div>

$("#btn").click(function() {//#btn is a submit button in the form
    document.getElementById("name").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("nameform").style.display="none";

});

$("#formname").submit(function () {
     $.ajax({
      url:"formname.php",
      data:$("#formname").serialize(),
      type:"POST",
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data=="xyz"){

            $("#formname")[0].reset();
            $("#formname").on("click",".sframe",f(0));
        } 
      },
      error:function(data){
        alert("Network error");
      }
    })
   return false;
 });
```

Comment: look into ajax. It allows you to update divs without reloading the page.

Comment: You have wrong syntax in line 3: `</div`

Comment: I have added the ajax function that is used to upload the name.Can you please tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: @user3774008 Code that you have in the question itself is formname.php ? If not, what exactly does formname.php output after update was done?

Comment: it inserts data in mysql and returns "xyz"(echo "xyz"; at the end in the php script)

Comment: Then all you need is:

`if(data=="xyz"){
// debug
alert('updated');
$("#name").text(//the name);

            $("#formname")[0].reset();
            $("#formname").on("click",".sframe",f(0));
        }`

Comment: how to obtain the name as the above content you specified is in js file and I would have to extract the name from database in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have written insertion code in ajax page formname.php.  On Ajax call if the name successfully inserted in database you fetch the name using your select query

```
$query1=mysqli_query($dbc,"select * from users where Email='".$_SESSION['Email']."'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
$name=$row['name'];
```

and echo the user name. 
else 
   echo "0" for error handling .

now in your ajax call script instead of

```
if(data=="xyz"){

        $("#formname")[0].reset();
        $("#formname").on("click",".sframe",f(0));
    }
```

put

```
 if(data!=0){

        $("#name").text(data); // It will put the name in the div
        $("#formname").on("click",".sframe",f(0));
    }
 else
  {
    alert("Data insertion error");
  }
```

Comment: here wont it be insecure to echo the name of the user?

Comment: The only way to interact with server without page reload is ajax call. So If you are familiar with MVC architecture then We put our user interface in view file say nameform.php ( here you will put <div id="name"></div>) and logical part in controller file like formname.php . Now if you return data fromname.php to nameform.php through a ajax then it won't be a security issue because in order to send response of the ajax call you need to echo the data from fromname.php to nameform.php